# AWS SES integration with Java maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to integrate AWS SES in my project to send bulk emails .
I have almost searched in AWS SES doc links on their site ,but could not find easy and straight steps to follow . I was in loop to find how it works !!!! Every link has so many other links .

What I have
1.Eclipse ()
2.JDK
3.Spring and Hibernate integration
4.Pom.xml

For AWS
I updated my pom.xml with  aws group and artifact id
2. I can import all classes of AWS
3. I have account AWS
4.Download access key and secret key

Found all method to send emails.

But When I try  to send email I am getting some class not found exception .
I need to authentic my credentials . I unable to find the way to authentic my credentials

Can some help me ???

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any AWS libraries or AWS access key and secret key. AWS SES provides standard SMTP endpoint to send out email.

You just need to get SMTP configuration from AWS SES management console. With SMTP information, you can use any mail library e.g. JavaMail API or [Spring Mail](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html) to send out email.

Comment: Need to send email from different "FROM" ids ...so AWS SES API  would be suitable . I am almost done with basis set up ..I m looking some tutorial to demonstrate working example